# Comparing dictionary of list of dictionary/nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, comparison

There are two dict main and input, I want to validate the "input" such that all the keys in the list of dictionary and nested dictionary (if present/all keys are optional) matches that of the main if not the wrong/different key should be returned as the output.

```
main = "app":[{
    "name": str,
    "info": [
        {
        "role": str,
        "scope": {"groups": list}
        }
        ]
    },{
    "name": str,
    "info": [
        {"role": str}
            ]
}]

input_data = "app":[{
    'name': 'nms',
    'info': [
        {
        'role': 'user',
        'scope': {'groups': ['xyz']
                }
        }]
},{
    'name': 'abc', 
    'info': [
    {'rol': 'user'}
    ]
}]
```

when compared input with main the wrong/different key should be given as output, in this case

`['rol']`

Answer (score 1):

The [schema](https://pypi.org/project/schema/) module does exactly this.
You can catch `SchemaUnexpectedTypeError` to see which data doesn't match your pattern.

Also, make sure you don't use the word `input` as a variable name, as it's the name of a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = []
def print_dict(d):
    if type(d) == dict:
        for val in d.keys():
            df = d[val]
            try:
                if type(df) == list:
                    for i in range(0,len(df)):
                        if type(df[i]) == dict:
                            print_dict(df[i])
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            keys.append(val)
    else:
        try:
            x = d[0]
            if type(x) == dict:
                print_dict(d[0])
        except:
            pass
    return keys
keys_input = print_dict(input)
keys = []
keys_main = print_dict(main)
print(keys_input)

print(keys_main)

for i in keys_input[:]:
        if i in keys_main:
            keys_input.remove(i)
print(keys_input)
```

This has worked for me. you can check above code snippet and if any changes provide more information so any chances if required.

Comment: Dicts compare nested by default. There is no special action needed.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary and lists compare theire content nested by default.

`input_data == main` should result in the right output if you format your dicts correctly. Try adding curly brackets "{"/"}" arround your dicts. It should probably look like something like this:

```py
main = {"app": [{
    "name": str,
    "info": [
        {
        "role": str,
        "scope": {"groups": list}
        }
        ]
    },{
    "name": str,
    "info": [
        {"role": str}
            ]
}]}

input_data = {"app":[{
    'name': 'nms',
    'info': [
        {
        'role': 'user',
        'scope': {'groups': ['xyz']
                }
        }]
},{
    'name': 'abc',
    'info': [
    {'rol': 'user'}
    ]
}]}

input_data2 = {"app": [{
    'name': 'nms',
    'info': [
        {
            'role': 'user',
            'scope': {'groups': ['xyz']
                      }
        }]
}, {
    'name': 'abc',
    'info': [
        {'rol': 'user'}
    ]
}]}
```

Comparision results should look like this:

```py
input_data2 == input_data # True
main == input_data # False
```